# need to check the icon inside your apk (phonegap application)

Tags: android, cordova, google-play

We have created an Android App using Phonegap. When we upload this app on Play Store, the same error has been shown again and again. Although I have also tried many solutions, this is still not uploaded. Kindly give me suggestions how to solve this error. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From phonegap [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/config_ref_images.md.html):

```
<platform name="android">
              <icon src="res/android/ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
              <icon src="res/android/mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
              <icon src="res/android/hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
              <icon src="res/android/xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
     </platform>
```

in config.xml

Also makesure the names of images are inline with above declaration i.e. ldpi.png, mdpi.png and so on